# Determine $\int_C\frac{w^3}{w-z}dw$, where $C$ is the circle $w=r[cos(t) + i sin(t)]$, $0\le t \le 2\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

One part of the problem is to figure out the integral:

$\int_C\frac{w^3}{w-z}dw$, where $C$ is the circle $w=r[cos(t) + i sin(t)]$, $0\le t \le 2\pi$

when $z$ is inside of $C$, and the other part is when $z$ is outside of $C$.

To start, I am looking at Cauchy's Integral Formula:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$, which you can use to solve the equation for $z$ inside of $C$.

However, I am not sure how this equation helps me.  Obviously, $f(w) = w^3$, but I am still confused as to how I am supposed to use this information to solve the integral.

Am I supposed to find $f(z)$ and multiply it by $2\pi i$ to solve for the integral?  But then I am confused as to why I need to know that $C$ is the circle $w=r[cos(t) + i sin(t)] = re^{it}$.

Then, after that, for $z$ outside of $C$, I think the answer is equal to $0$, based on the book I am using to help me with this problem.  However, the explanation in the book is very poor and I don't understand *why* it is equal to $0$.  I would like to understand the solutions, not just have the solutions.

Any help would be really appreciated; even just something to get me started.  Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT.** You have the right idea. Use Cauchy's Integral Formula.
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} \;d\zeta
$$
or written differently, 
$$
2\pi i f(z)=\oint_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} \;d\zeta
$$
Then if $z$ is inside our curve $C$, the integral is $2\pi i f(z)$. If $z$ is outside our curve, what is the value of the integral?

More importantly (and you ask), why is it that if $z$ is outside of $C$ is the integral $0$? Well, in that case, is the function analytic? Is it over a closed curve? What is the value of the integral then?

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.  I guess the only question that remains is how I would find $f(z)$ to calculate the value of the integral?  Do I have to expand $f(w)$ into its Taylor Series?

And the information about $z$ being outside of $C$ is also helpful!  Thanks, again.